# Change MIDI octave before data reaches computer

Tags: midi

I teach guitar. I was hoping to use a MIDI-enabled guitar, in combination with an iPad, to help students learn notes, practice sight-reading, and practice playing by ear. They would stay before or after their lesson and play on some apps.

The problem is that the guitar is a transposing instrument. It sounds an octave below the written notes. Because of this, when I play the right note on the guitar, these apps registers the wrong note because, well, it kinda is.

However, all of these apps are incredibly rudimentary in their MIDI implementation. They have literally no MIDI settings; channel, virtual midi, anything. It's just MIDI on-off. This means that, to my knowledge and after some testing, a iPad-based software solution won't work.

I'm wondering what the the simplest, lowest latency, least expensive way of changing the octave of the notes would be. My first thought is an Arduino or Raspberry Pi built into a stomp box. But MIDI really isn't something I've messed around with. A friend mentioned Super Collider, Python, and Pure Data as maybe the best way to do it.

Note that my device is USB. A Fishman Triple Play Connect.

Also, as a side-note, these apps do accept audio from a mic, but I need this to be as close to silent as possible (students will be wearing headphones and playing an unamplified electric guitar). Using my external audio interface was so friggin' buggy that I thought hacking something together with a RPi would be an easier solution.

Comment: If you teach the students the right notes in absolute terms, won't you be teaching then the wrong written notes for the guitar - which is the instrument they'll actually be playing? It sounds potentially quite confusing for the student....

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica I think the idea is exactly the opposite - to get the notes to show up correctly like it's written for guitar, not in "concert pitch" like the apps are currently showing them.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica aha, yep, that's probably right. Never mind me... I was assuming that these apps would deal with audio in some way too...

Comment: Isn't the TriplePlay Connect thingy supposed to have settings for this. If it doesn't, then this is Fishman's fault as much as anyone else's. :)

Comment: Well, OK, let's take a step back. A guitar is a transposing instrument, whose notes are registered transposed by the software because they are transposed. I don't see a problem.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica On the cheaper, wired Triple Play, there are two switches, which can be programed for various uses. However, those settings do not persist across apps; they are only effective within Fishman's app. Tested by setting them to change octave, then using them in another app. In the test app, they changed patches (which is their default setting). These educational apps definitely aren't sophisticated enough to have any ability to pay attention to octave changes, and, given my test, I'm assuming that takes place on the software side, not on the controller.

Comment: @Hatebit The Guitar MIDI device outputs C4, which is the correct note to play when C5 is notated. These basic education apps (3 tested) on the iPad doen't know they are receiving transposed MIDI data and thus registers this as an incorrect answer. None of these apps have any MIDI settings available other than on/off.

Comment: If you want a fun project, try an Arduino or Raspi based router/processor. Raspi might be able to do USB I/O in both directions. I recently made an Arduino box like that, DIN MIDI IN+OUT with proper opto isolators and all, guitar pedal compatible 9V power in, small graphical OLED display, mostly improvised mash-up schematic, and even an RJ-45 connector so I can control it with my old Line6 Floorboard which uses an ethernet cable for _analog_ I/O for the switches, wah/volume controller and LEDs. Building it was a great learning experience. I haven't used it too much yet though. ;)

Comment: @Kale There is no such thing as transposed MIDI data. Not in the classical sense. There is simply no provision in MIDI for saying "these notes are transposed". as far as I know. That's because MIDI doesn't deal with classical notation. This is also where it gets interesting: a C4 or C5 are just conventions that do not necessarily correspond to any notational system for octave numbering. It's mostly a choice of software, somewhat like level meter markings. What I am trying to say is, you are creating more problems by trying to solve this particular (non-)problem. C4 vs C5 is a moot point.

Comment: @Hatebit The problem is - student plays a note on a transposing instrument, and it appears in notation in _concert pitch_, which is _wrong_ for that instrument's notation. That is the problem. Can you list the problems that trying to solve this causes?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica 1) being put off/abandoning the original solution 2) real-time processing bottlenecks due to lack of built-in MIDI processing 3) trying to bend the implementation 4) unnecessary costs due to implementing a hardware solution for a software problem, to start with

Answer (score 4):

### Arduino

Would be a latency free and simple solution, given the [Arduino MIDI library](https://github.com/FortySevenEffects/arduino_midi_library). However, I am not sure you can receive from a device and send to another using *USB-MIDI*. Using a board with several Serial ports would work, but you need to convert your USB-MIDI signal to a "plain MIDI" with a DIN5 cable… And then the other way around…

### Pi

You can run a very simple audio system on a Pi, using [Jack](https://jackaudio.org/), and then use some utilities like [QMidiRoute](https://github.com/royvegard/qmidiroute), which is basically allowing you to change your (USB) MIDI signals any way you want. I would think it is much more easier than SuperCollider and so which are much more audio focused. If you can afford the booting time and need for it to be plugged, I think this is the simplest to do it! It could be able to route several guitars at the same time, like a transposing server!

### Using a MIC

You can probably "lure" the mic by using a full wave [rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier). This will make a crunch signal at twice the frequency of the original. If I remember well, this is what is done by a lot of guitar pedals like Fuzz, Muff. If you have diods in it, you have a good chance they will rectify.

No definitive answer but hope it helps!